# .Net 6.0 Core Web API Application not Releasing Memory

Tags: .net, .net-core, memory-management, asp.net-core-webapi, .net-6.0

I'm currently working on a .NET 6 Web API project, and I'm facing an issue with memory not being released properly. Despite attempting to force garbage collection using GC.Collect(), the memory usage keeps increasing over time, leading to performance degradation.

I have thoroughly analyzed the code and ensured that I'm not creating any memory leaks or holding onto unnecessary resources. However, the memory consumption continues to rise, even during idle periods.

I have tried the following steps to address the issue:

Ensured that all disposable objects are properly disposed of using using statements or explicit calls to Dispose().

Created a new blank .NET 6 Project , but the same , Memory is not releasing

To mitigate the problem, I resorted to using GC.Collect() explicitly at certain intervals, hoping it would release the unused memory. However, this approach doesn't seem to be effective, and the memory usage keeps growing.

Is there anything specific to .NET 6 or Web API that I should be aware of regarding memory management? What could be causing the memory not to release properly, even after forcing garbage collection? Are there any additional steps I can take to troubleshoot and resolve this issue?

Any help or insights would be greatly appreciated. Thank you!

Release Mode Memory not released

[image]

Same happening with IIS Worker Process when i hosted the application

[image]

Comment: You should create a memory snapshot #1 and after some time #2 and see a difference - using Visual Studio Diagnostic Tools.

Answer (score 3):

I had the same problem and I tested disabling ServerGarbageCollection property in *.csproj file. I'm doing a load testing and it seems to be working.
[image]